# Recorrer la estructura cambiante de un objeto JavaScript sin utilizar funciones recursivas ¿Es posible?

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, recursión, javascript-objeto

> **NOTA:**
>
> Antes de empezar con la pregunta describo un poco el contexto para exponer la interrogante que surge en esta publicación.

### Contexto de la pregunta

Tengo el objeto `temas` que puedo recorrer utilizando el bucle **for** de la siguiente manera:

```js
// Objeto temas:
let temas = {
  asignatura: "Matemáticas",
  actividad: "Límites y Derivadas"
};

// Que se recorre con este bucle:
for ( let tema in temas ) {
  console.log( `${tema}: ${temas[tema]}` );
}
```

Pero, si cambiamos su estructura, entonces tengo que reescribir el código que lo recorrerá. Por ejemplo:

```js
// Función que evaluará si el objeto temas o sus
// propiedades son un objeto:
const isObject = ( valor ) => {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call( valor ) === "[object Object]";
};

// Objeto temas con su estructura cambiada:
let temas = {
  matematicas: {
    objetivo: "Límites y Derivadas",
    docente: "Pablo Pérez Delgado"
  },

  fisica: {
    objetivo: "Leyes de Newton",
    docente: "Julia Piña"
  },

  institucion: "UNEFA"
};

// Bucle que lo recorrerá, pero reescrito ahora:
for ( let tema in temas ) {
  if ( isObject( temas[tema] ) ) {
    // Si «tema» es un objeto se debe recorrer mediante el
    // el siguiente bucle:
    for ( let propiedad in temas[tema] ) {
      console.log( `${propiedad}: ${temas[tema][propiedad]}` );
    }
  }else {
    // De lo contrario, se mostrará en la consola:
    console.log( `${tema}: ${temas[tema]}` );
  }
}
```

Por lo tanto, para evitar la situación de reescribir el código que recorrerá (en este caso, el bucle **for**) la estructura del objeto **`temas`** tuve que utilizar una función recursiva.

**Por ejemplo:**

```js
// Objeto al que se le recorrerá su estructura:
let temas = {
  matematicas: {
    objetivo: "Límites y Derivadas",
    docente: "Pablo Pérez Delgado"
  },

  fisica: {
    objetivo: "Leyes de Newton",
    docente: "Julia Piña",
  },

  institucion: "UNEFA"
};

// Nos ayudará a evaluar si el objeto «temas» o sus propiedades 
// son un objeto:
const isObject = ( valor ) => {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call( valor ) === "[object Object]";
};

// Función que utilizará la recursión para
// recorrer la estructura del objeto «temas»:
const recorrer = ( objeto ) => {
  for ( let propiedad in objeto ) {
    isObject( objeto[propiedad] )
    ? recorrer( objeto[propiedad] )
    : console.log( `${propiedad}: ${objeto[propiedad]}` );
  }
};

// Recorrer la estructura del objeto «temas»
// al llamar la función recorrer:
recorrer( temas );
```

#### Esta es mi pregunta

¿Es posible recorrer la **estructura cambiante de un objeto** sin necesidad de recurrir a funciones recursivas?

> **Nota:** con **estructura cambiante de un objeto** me refiero a que al objeto en cuestión se le cambie su estructura.

---

> El planteamiento de esta publicación puede **extrapolarse** de forma análoga a los **arreglos (Arrays)**.

Comment: ¿ Quieres limitar la profundidad (el número de niveles dentro de los objetos contenidos), ¿ O quieres hacerlo sea cual sea el número de objetos recursivos contenidos ?

Comment: Voy por la segunda opción. Hacerlo sea cual sea el número de objetos recursivos contenidos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como no quieres limitar la *profundidad* de la exploración, no te queda mas remedio que usar una estructura auxiliar: bien una pila, bien una cola.

**¡¡ Cuidado !!** Sin limitar el nivel de profundidad, puedes llegar a bucles infinitos. Recuerda que, en Javascript, los objetos se usan mediante referencias, lo que posibilita la existencia de bucles: el objeto A contiene al objeto B, que, a su vez, contiene al objeto A, que a su vez contiene el B, ... Si intentas recorrer un objeto así, tu código fallará (la aplicación se quedará sin memoria).

```js
let temas = {
  matematicas: {
    objetivo: "Límites y Derivadas",
    docente: "Pablo Pérez Delgado"
  },

  fisica: {
    objetivo: "Leyes de Newton",
    docente: "Julia Piña"
  },

  institucion: "UNEFA"
};

function recorrer( obj ) {
  let pila = [ [ '', obj ] ];

  while( pila.length ) {
    let curr = pila.pop( );

    if( ( typeof( curr[1] ) == 'object' ) && ( curr[1] ) ) {
      for( let idx in curr[1] ) {
        if( ( typeof( curr[1] ) == 'object' ) && ( curr[1] ) ) {
          if( curr[0].length ) {
            pila.push( [ `${curr[0]}.${idx}`, curr[1][idx] ] );
          } else {
            pila.push( [ idx, curr[1][idx] ] );
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      console.log( `${curr[0]}: ${curr[1]}` );
    }
  }
}

recorrer( temas );
```